# Visualforce email template IF condition for Second Opportunity Owner field

Tags: visualforce, email, if, template

I have an email alert that goes out when an Opportunity is changed to Closed Won and it says who the Opportunity Owner is. Sometimes, a second salesperson is involved in the deal, so I have a field called Second Opportunity Owner. I only want that line to show in the email when Second Opportunity Owner is filled in.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="New Buyer Opportunity Closed Won: {!relatedTo.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
{!relatedTo.Owner.name} is pleased to report that {!relatedTo.Name} for {!relatedTo.Account.name} has moved to the closed won stage.  Nicely done. 

{!relatedTo.Second.Opportunity.Owner__c} also played a part in closing this deal. Great teamwork! - this is where I'd like to add this ideally

The revenue for this project is ${!relatedTo.Amount_this_Year__c} which is the projected amount based on conversations in the closing stages. This amount may also include the use of multiple services. See below:

<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}" var="line">
{!line.Name}
</apex:repeat>

Congratulations again.  Widen is pleased to welcome {!relatedTo.Account.name} to the customer family consisting of the most powerful brands in the world.

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(relatedTo.Second_Opportunity_Owner__c))">
{!relatedTo.Second_Opportunity_Owner__r.Name}
</apex:outputText>
```

Use the `rendered=` attribute to detect if the lookup field is present

Note also your syntax for the second opportunity owner was incorrect, assuming the custom field is `Second_Opportunity_Owner__c` and is a lookup to User.